# how could mvcc works when the primary key is changed?

Tags: innodb

In MVCC document, it says when "select query" finds the records, it will compare the transactionId with its own id to judge if the data can be seen and if history records should be reconstructed from redo log. My question is what if it cannot find the original records, and how could it maintain consistent reading?

Consider the following example:

```
create table tb_a (id bigtint not null primary key auto_increment, name varchar(100) not null default "");
 // isolation level is RR

// transaction 1
select * from tb_a where id = 1;  // it returns (1, "a")

// transaction 2
// another trx update the first line with its primary key
update tb_a set id = 3 where id = 1;
commit;

// transaction 1
select * from tb_a where id = 1; // still gets (1, "a")
```

the primary key with the filter id = 1 cannot find the row since the history records are in redo log, and updates in innodb happen inplace. So how does innodb treat this kind of thing and still maintains consistency?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the PK column is probably a "delete" of the old record and an "insert" of the new row.  I think this implies that something is left in the table, but marked as deleted (until the cleanup after Commits from both transactions).

Similarly for `UNIQUE` key changes.  Other transactions need to be able to see the deleted row to check for dup key.

Each version of each row (old/new) has a transaction id.  So...

**Repeatable Read:**

When a transaction starts, it is assigned a "transaction id".  This is a monotonically increasing sequence number for identifying rows that might be modified.  For transaction isolation = RR, the queries can only "see" rows that have that trx id (or older).  This explains why your final `SELECT` sees what it does.  And, note, that query is actually (as far as I know) re-executed.

Your other txn had a higher trx id.  It created a 'newer' copy of the row.  So, there were at least two copies of that row floating around.  The isolation mode, plus the trx id, controls which row each transaction can "see".

Comment: I don't think select in 1 locks this role. Select is none-locking read which uses version instead of lock.

Comment: @makiXIE - I made major changes to my Answer.  The History List is the secret sauce, not Locks.

Comment: I remember that in the clustered index, the mechanics do not create a new row but change in place and update the pointer in the row head to redo log so that other transaction who finds the transaction is larger will go back to redo log and reconstruct the previous version. Only the secondary index creates new copy on change. @RickJames

Comment: @makiXIE - Changes to any secondary index are buffered/delayed via the "change buffer".

Comment: but the case here is the primary key, thus clustered key. Not related to secondary index.